# using an array as a function argument in Lua

Tags: arrays, function, lua

I have 2 files test.lua and test2.lua.
In test1.lua:
`require "test" test.fn(arg)`

In test.lua:
`function test.fn(arr) for i=1, #arr do print (arr[i]) end end`

In short, I need the array to be the argument of the function, but I keep getting an error.

I was trying to "equate" the arg array to the new f array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're not setting a global `test` table up in `test.lua`. Thus setting `test.fn` should fail with "attempt to index a nil value".

Second, newer Lua versions (5.1 and later) do not have the `arg` table. Instead, they more elegantly use the vararg `...` for command line arguments. You can pack `...` in a table using `{...}`.

The following code should work as expected:

###### `test.lua`

```
test = {} -- first set up the test table
function test.fn(arr)
    for i=1, #arr do
        print(arr[i])
    end
end
```

###### `test2.lua`

```lua
require"test"
test.fn({...}) -- pack the vararg in a table before passing it
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'm new to lua, the problem I described occurred when trying to split a terminal application into 2 files:) you have helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in C Style with...

```
-- argvc.lua
local function func(...)
local argv = {...} -- Define a table
local argc = #argv -- Length of the table

for i = 1, argc do -- Put out formated what we have
  print(("Argument %d/%d => %s"):format(i, argc, argv[i]))
end

return(argc) -- returning the Length
end

return(func) -- This make it requireable ;-)
```

Example of use...

```
$ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> argvc = require("argvc")
> argvc(debug.getinfo(argvc).short_src, _VERSION, math.pi)
Argument 1/3 => ./argvc.lua
Argument 2/3 => Lua 5.4
Argument 3/3 => 3.1415926535898
3
> test = {fn = require("argvc")}
> test.fn('Hi There')
Argument 1/1 => Hi There
1
> test:fn('Hi There')
Argument 1/2 => table: 0x5666eb80
Argument 2/2 => Hi There
2
```